# Using SVG file, not inline-svg, as CSS Mask?

Tags: css, svg

i want to use a SVG as CSS mask, but since i want users to be able to upload the SVG themselves, the SVG is not embedded in the code, but it's own file instead.

I saw multiple explanations on how to use SVG as a mask but it always referred to the ID of an Inline SVG Code, that was embedded in the page, but never referred to using an external SVG

Right now i am using a PNG as mask, but i'd prefer a vector solution instead of a pixel solution.

Here's my results so far:
https://codepen.io/hergi/pen/bGwXOOw

```css
.logo {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10vh;
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}


}
```

```html
<div>PNG Mask:</div>
<div class="logo" style="mask: url(https://i.imgur.com/2nxTeqy.png) no-repeat center / contain;
      -webkit-mask: url(https://i.imgur.com/2nxTeqy.png) no-repeat center / contain;">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2nxTeqy.png" />
</div>

<div>SVG Mask (css mask):</div>
<div class="logo" style="mask: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Ta9.svg) no-repeat center / contain;
      -webkit-mask: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Ta9.svg) no-repeat center / contain;">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2nxTeqy.png" />
</div>

<div>SVG Mask (css mask-image):</div>
<div class="logo" style="mask-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Ta9.svg) no-repeat center / contain;
      -webkit-mask-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Ta9.svg) no-repeat center / contain;">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2nxTeqy.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: open the console and you will read *Access to image at 'https://svgshare.com/i/Ta9.svg' from origin 'https://cdpn.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Comment: Oh - i did not realize this. Can you tell me what that means for me? im guessing that would be something like that the svg was not properly loaded for security reasons or whatever?

Comment: it means that your code is fine and you have a sever issue and you need to upload you file somewhere else. mask is a bit tricky and not all the file are accepted due to security reason: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394277/8620333

Comment: thanks for your input, ill try it out locally and will update an answer accordingly